# undefined method `model_name', Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to implement simple form in home#index page using:

```
<%= render "forms/form"%>
```

Form look like this:

```
<%= form_for(@form) do |f| %>
  <% if @form.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@form.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this form from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @form.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :defect %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :defect %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :region %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :region %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

But when I access that page, I got this error message:

```
undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
```

First of all I though it is because my model name is also Form, but then I checked Rails 3 reserved words, but there wasn't "form" !

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In home controller, set the instance variable `@form` in the index action as:-

```
def index
  @form = Form.new
end
```

Comment: @EdgarsRozenfelds so which model's form do you want to render in your view? Is it `Form` model?

Comment: I already tried at the first time like you suggested, with Form.new.

Comment: @EdgarsRozenfelds are you sure it's correct action? Please show all your controller.

Answer (score 2):

Your `@form` instance variable's value is `nil`. You should set it in controller.